# Azure notification hub throws socket exception

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

We use Azure notification hubs to send push messages to our customers mobile devices. Sometimes we get several `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`. These exceptions are for Android devices (FCM/GCM) as well as iOS devices (APN). 
Has anyone else experienced this behaviour (and hopefully solved it)?